# Merging two repositories with the github API

Tags: git-merge, github-api

Octokit has a [`Octokit::Client::Commits#merge`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pengwynn/octokit/Octokit/Client/Commits#merge-instance_method) method to merge.

Is it possible to use this method (or another one) to merge a branch from another repository?

I tried with:

```
client.merge('user1/repo', 'master', 'user2:master')
```

and

```
client.merge('user1/repo', 'master', 'user2/master')
```

but it doesn't seem to work…

Comment: I'd use an SHA1 instead of a branch name just in case you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only merge branches from within a repository not from another, whether the other is a fork or not. You might do:

```
repo = client.repository('user2/repo')
system "git clone #{repo['git_url']}"  # this may be wrong, I've never used Octokit
# change into the directory
system "git checkout #{branch}"
system "git push git@github.com:user1/repo #{branch}"
client.merge('user1/repo', 'master', 'alt_branch')
```